# Auto detect the type of reference property of a given class object

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Given a class like this

```
public class Employee
{
   public Employee()
   {
       Children = new List<Child>();
   }
   public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
   public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
   public virtual EmployeeCard EmployeeCard { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; protected set; }
}
```

If I have an object of the above class, how to determine if the `EmployeeCard` property is an object or a list of object at run time? Is this possible?

Comment: `EmployeeCard`, without seeing the class definition of it, looks to be a single object. You can't assign an array to what would contain a single object, so you shouldn't need to examine it at runtime. How is it possible that could contain either a list or a single object?

Comment: Ron is completely right.  If it was a list, the type would be IList<EmployeeCard> or such.  One of the benefits of a strongly-typed language is being able to see at a glance such information.

Comment: Hmmm.  How can it ever become a list?  It's defined as a single object ....

Comment: I need it at runtime not to assign an array to it, but to create dynamic report of unknown object type(maybe Employee, EmployeeCard, ......)  so according to the type and relations between the classes I need to generate the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the type of the property implements `IEnumerable`:

```
bool isCollection = 
   typeof(Employee).GetProperty("EmployeeCard")
                   .PropertyType
                   .GetInterface("IEnumerable")
     != null;
```

This should work for all generic and non-generic collection types, including `IList<T>`

Comment: does this give me if the property is a list of objects or an object??

Comment: Like the answer says, yes, because `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are referring to this line of code in your example:
 `public virtual EmployeeCard EmployeeCard{ get; set; }`

First I should point out that using the same case on your method name and your class/struct name is not good practice and in some cases could cause problems with your compiler. Second, as far as I know, since you have it set to return a single object (EmployeeCard) you cannot have the non-virtual version of this method return an array of that type. What I recommend is that you go ahead and always return an array, and then check the length of the array, like this:

```
public virtual EmployeeCard[] _EmployeeCard { get; set; }
```

and declare your override using :

```
private EmployeeCard[] _employeeCards;

public override EmployeeCard[] _EmployeeCard
{
    get{
        return _employeeCards;
    }
    set{
        _employeeCards = (EmployeeCard[])value;
    }
}
```

When you reference it, and want to know if they have more than 1 you can do this:

```
if(myEmployee._EmployeeCard.Length > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Employee has {0} cards.", myEmployee._EmployeeCard
}
```

I haven't tested this code yet because I'm at work but I think there is enough here that you can get the idea. Hopefully I haven't misunderstood what you are actually trying to do here, and I had to assume a few things since you didn't post your code for the class/struct named EmployeeCard.

Cheers,

Keith